# Symmetrical sums

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-jx/n}}{n^2}-\frac{e^{-nx/j}}{j^2}\right ),x>0$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{nj}} \left (\frac{e^{-j/n}}{n}-\frac{e^{-n/j}}{j}  \right )\right )$$
Two sums are given. As you can see, they are symmetrical, but there is a problem. If I understand correctly, the first sum will equal $0$, but the second sum for some reason does not. Question: why is the second sum not equal to $0$ if it is symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny enough, but the second sum can also be presented in the closed form. More generally, let's consider
$$S_2(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\sqrt{nj}} \left (\frac{e^{-jx/n}}{n}-\frac{e^{-nx/j}}{j}  \right )\right );\,\,x>0$$
Using the same approach as below for the first sum, we can present the second sum as an integral:
$$S_2(x)=\int_1^\infty\frac{ds}{\sqrt s}\int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\Big(\frac{e^{-sx/t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-tx/s}}{s}\Big)$$
Making the substitution $p=\frac{1}{t}$
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt t}\frac{e^{-sx/t}}{t}=\int_0^1\frac{e^{-xps}}{\sqrt p}dp=\frac{2}{\sqrt s}\int_0^\sqrt se^{-xt^2}dt\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{1}{s}\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-tx/s}}{\sqrt t}dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt s}\int_{1/\sqrt s}^\infty e^{-xt^2}dt\tag{2}$$
Using (1) and (2) and making the substitution $s\to\frac{1}{s}$
$$S_2(x)=2\int_1^\infty\frac{ds}{s}\Big(\int_0^\sqrt se^{-xt^2}dt-\int_{1/\sqrt s}^\infty e^{-xt^2}dt\Big)=\int_0^\infty\frac{ds}{s}\Big(\int_0^\sqrt se^{-xt^2}dt-\int_{1/\sqrt s}^\infty e^{-xt^2}dt\Big)$$
Integrating by part,
$$=\ln s\Big(\int_0^\sqrt se^{-xt^2}dt-\int_{1/\sqrt s}^\infty e^{-xt^2}dt\Big)\bigg|_{s=0}^{s=\infty}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\Big(\frac{e^{-sx}}{\sqrt s}-\frac{e^{-x/s}}{s^{3/2}}\Big)\ln s\,ds$$
Making the change in the second term $s\to\frac{1}{s}$, we can present the sum in the form
$$S_2(x)=-\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln s}{\sqrt s}e^{-sx}ds$$
$$=-\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\,\Big|_{t=0}\int_0^\infty s^{-1/2+t}e^{-s}ds-\ln x\int_0^\infty s^{-1/2}e^{-s}ds\Big)$$
$$\boxed{\,\,S_2(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\Big(\Gamma\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\psi\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)-\ln x\,\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)\bigg)=\sqrt\pi\,\frac{\gamma+2\ln2+\ln x}{\sqrt x}\,\,}$$

Answer (score 2):

In fact, both sums are not zero: every term of every sum diverges, so we are not allowed to change the order of summation.
On the other hand, any finite summation (till any finite $N$) is zero - due to the antisymmetry (for a finite $N$ we are allowed to change the order of summation).

For example, for the first sum we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^N\left ( \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{e^{-jx/n}}{n^2}-\frac{e^{-nx/j}}{j^2}\right )=0$$
Therefore,
$$S_1(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-jx/n}}{n^2}-\frac{e^{-nx/j}}{j^2}\right )=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{j=N}^\infty\left ( \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{e^{-jx/n}}{n^2}-\frac{e^{-nx/j}}{j^2}\right )$$
$$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{j=N}^\infty\left ( \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{e^{-(jx/N)/(n/N)}}{n^2/N^2}-\frac{e^{-(nx/N)/(j/N)}}{j^2/N^2}\right )=\int_1^\infty ds\bigg(\int_1^\infty dt\Big(\frac{e^{-sx/t}}{t^2}-\frac{e^{-tx/s}}{s^2}\Big)\bigg)$$
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-sx/t}}{t^2}dt=\frac{1-e^{-xs}}{xs}\tag{1}$$
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-tx/s}}{s^2}dt=\frac{e^{-x/s}}{xs}\tag{2}$$
Using (1) and (2), and making the change $s=\frac{1}{t}$
$$S_1(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_1^\infty\frac{1-e^{-sx}-e^{-x/s}}{s}ds=\frac{1}{2x}\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-sx}-e^{-x/s}}{s}ds$$
Integrating by part,
$$=\frac{1}{2x}\ln s\,\big(1-e^{-sx}-e^{-x/s}\big)\,\bigg|_0^\infty-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\ln s\Big(e^{-xs}-\frac{e^{-x/s}}{s^2}\Big)ds$$
$$\boxed{\,\,S_1(x)=-\int_0^\infty\ln s\,e^{-xs}ds=\frac{\gamma+\ln x}{x}\,\,}$$

Comment: Do I understand it correctly? If the amounts are over, they are zero? The first one will equal zero if it is finite. The second will also be zero if it is finite? What then if the second sum is infinite?

Comment: For any finite $N$ both sums are zero; therefore, we can evaluate them as a limit at $N\to\infty$ (what I did with the first sum as an example). In the same way (switching from summation to the Riemann sums and integration) we can do with the second sum in order to evaluate it . (Though, these integrals look more complicated than in the first case)

Comment: As I mentioned above, both sums (summation till $\infty$) are not zero.